# Autohotkey remapping alt+j to left but alt+shift+j doesn't select left nor do alt+ctr+j move a caret , if getKeyState does not work

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

Basically,

It's inspired by Vim I want to use a key(e.g <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>F1</kbd>) combination(+I J K L) to map to Arrow Keys

What is already done in Autohotkey

```
Ralt & j::send{Left}
Ralt & k::send{Right}
```

...
Now I take <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> as up etc,which is pretty fine for me But the problem comes when you press

```
Ralt+Shift+j  (Suppose to select the last charater)
Ralt+Ctrl+j   (Suppose to move a caramel text)
```

These kind of combination would not work and it just get overrided to basic move cursor to left

Even if I use if/while statement with `GetKeyState`, it doesn't gonna work

```
if GetKeyState("Shift","P")
   Ralt+j::send +{Left}
This kind of stuff didn't work
```

Any Ideas on that ?It would make coding very efficient without having to move the right hand.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing 2 things:

1. Must use a `#` symbol when doing a [context sensitive hotkey](http://l.autohotkey.net/docs/commands/_If.htm)
2. The bottom section of code is using a `+` instead of the `&` you used previously.

See the below modification:

```
RAlt & j:: Send {Left}
RAlt & k:: Send {Right}

#If GetKeyState("Shift","P")
   RAlt & j:: Send +{Left}
   RAlt & k:: Send +{Right}

; Close with #If to remove the context or simply start another '#If GetKeystate ....'
```